# What's the meaning of "chips and nicks"?

Tags: expressions, slang, vernacular

I watched a video in which somebody had just had his car painted, but a rock fell on it and took away some of the paint. While I was translating video subtitles, I heard this expression: "chips and nicks".

I haven't figured out its meaning. Based on the context, I think it should be slang meaning something unpleasant. Could you plz help me about it?

Comment: *Based on the context,* What context? You have not given any context. You may have forgotten that none of us have seen the video...

Comment: somebody just had his car painted, but a rock fell on the small car and took away some of the paint. "chips and nicks" is used here to refer to unpleasant situations like this

Comment: It's merely a list of two possible types of damage (I'm not sure of the difference intended by professionals). 'Chips and nicks' isn't a fixed phrase.  In fact, 'nicks and chips' seems more common on the internet, while 'scuffs, chips and nicks' and 'chips, nicks, and scratches' also make an appearance.

Comment: When you encounter an unfamiliar word or words, look it or them up in a dictionary. If English isn't your first language, try a translating dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

A chip refers to (i) **the area from which** a small piece of surface material (in this case, paint) has been removed by a sharp impact with a small, hard object. **or** (ii) **a small piece of surface material** (in this case, paint) that has been removed by a sharp impact with a small, hard object.

OED:

> **1.a. A small piece or fragment of any relatively hard substance, typically one broken or split from a larger piece by means of a sharp
> blow or knock**

A nick is a cut or scratch that penetrates the surface (in this case, of the pain.)

OED

> **7. A cut; (now esp.) a minor one**

Neither is slang.

Comment: How is this a suitable question for ELU, Greybeard?

Comment: The OP was looking for a meaning of what he thought was a slang phrase in the English language. Both nouns have several meanings.

Comment: Both the definitions you list are readily available; OP omits the inclusion of basic research.

Comment: I rather think that the OP saw "chips and nicks" as a single phrase - searching for "chips and nicks" is not going to help. I hope my answer steered him from that error.

Comment: This gets back to the 'answer in comment' (which I'd already given) debate. Where no research is shown, an 'answer' encourages other questions discouraged at the Help Center.